# Passing parameters to a Spring Batch Job

Tags: spring-batch

I want to process 3 data files. Lets say `FileA`,`FileB`,`FileC`. Each file has different type of data and will be loaded to different set of tables. I have read about Spring Batch and have seen videos and have done some tutorials. I am thinking of writing a series of `Steps` for each type of file. For example, my `FileProcessingJob` will have `FileA-Step1`, `FileA-Step2`, `FileA-Step3` for `FileA` and then `FileB-Step1`, `FileB-Step2`, `FileB-Step3` for `FileB` and `FileC-Step1`, `FileC-Step2`, `FileC-Step3` for `FileC`. I want to pass File Name to `FileProcessingJob` as parameter and want to execute appropriate series of steps. For example, when `FileA` is passed to `FileProcessingJob`, `FileA-Step1`, `FileA-Step2`, `FileA-Step3` should be executed. I have read and understand how to chain steps in required sequence. What I have not been able to find and read is as how to pass parameter(s) to `Spring Batch Job`. Can someone point me to the info?

Comment: Use a JobExecutionDecider to flow to right steps (FileA or B or C) depending on your job parameter

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, you need 3 different Readers. (Steps are another story which you might need, but if you have 3 different file types, you will need a reader for every type).

Regarding the Job Parameters - I assume [this link can help: Spring's Doc - Configuring a Job](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html). Basically, when the launcher run a job, it passes it an object called JobParameters. This is what you need. You can define a parameter in the XML config file, for example...)